# Django reverse() method still throwing NoReverseMatch exception error even after adding the application name space

Tags: python, django

**This is my urls.py file with my route names.**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
app_name = "procurement"
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('my_redirect/',views.my_redirect, name="my_redirect"),
    path('members/', views.members, name="members"),
    path('addMember/', views.addMember, name="addMember"),
    path('removeMember/', views.removeMember, name="removeMember"),
    path('requisition/', views.new_requisition, name="new_requisition"),
    path('user_department', views.user_department, name="user_department"),
    path('part1_requisition', views.part1_requisition, name="part1_requisition"),
    path('back_to_requisition_part1/', views.back_to_requisition_part1, name="back_to_requisition_part1"),
    path('part2_requisition/', views.part2_requisition, name="part2_requisition"),
    path('part3_requisition/', views.part3_requisition, name="part3_requisition"),
    path('ajax_filter', views.ajax_filter, name="ajax_filter"),
    path('pdu', views.pdu, name="pdu"),
    path('accounting_officer', views.accounting_officer, name="accounting_officer")
]
```

**And in my views.py file, I have something like this:**

```
    @login_required
    def ajax_filter(request):
        """
        Filter's ajax requests.
        """
        if request.is_ajax():
            first_name = "Byenkya"
            if first_name:
                return JsonResponse({
                    "success": True,
                    "url": reverse('procurement:part3_requisition', args=[first_name]),
                })
        return JsonResponse({ "success": False })
```

**I really don't know why the reverse function is still raising the exception even after adding the namespace. Please someone help am new to django.**

Comment: There is no parameter in your `path`, hence the `args=[first_name]` will not work.

Comment: where in your `urlpatterns` the path `part3_requisition` with `args`?

Comment: thanks i realized my mistake. thank you very much.